# How do I move this search icon to the right on focus so it follows the input field?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a expanding search bar on focus, and move the icon to the right as the input field expands. Something like this:

[image]

Where the red square is the search icon. This is the code so far:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.search-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.search-button {
  color: #fff;
}

.search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 49px;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.search:focus {
  width: 363px;
  padding: 0 0 0 16px;
}

.search:focus+.search-button {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  left: 363px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="/logo.png">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form>
    <input class="search" id="search" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
    <label class="search-button" for="search"><i class="icon"></i>SI</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

On focus, it already expands the input field. What do I need to change here to make this work, so that the icon follow the input and stays on top, like on the picture above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your code like below. The trick is to play with the direction to make the expand effect easier to handle without the need of `position:absolute` on the input element.

```css
.search-wrapper {
  max-width:30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 100px;
  direction: rtl; /* this is important for the trick */
}
.search-container {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block; /* This one is also important to allow the  element to overflow */
  height: 50px;
}

.search-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.search {
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  direction: ltr;  /* we reset the direction here */
}

.search:focus {
  width: 363px;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-width: 1280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <form class="search-container">
      <input class="search" id="search" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
      <label class="search-button" for="search"><i class="icon">SI</i></label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working great, thank you! Just one issue. When it expands, it moves the content beside it. How do I fix that?

Comment: @hemoglobin what kind of content? there is no content in your question

Comment: This is part of the menu. Sorry if I neglected to show that. I've added just one <li></li> element to show. Should I add the rest as well?

Comment: @hemoglobin yes, because I cannot know how the other content is made. I only answered based on the one your provided

Comment: I apologize. It's added in now, the layout of the navigation menu.